# Понимание принципов перемещения по маршрутам в Flutter

Tags: flutter

Кто работал с маршрутами: https://flutter.su/tutorial/5-navigacija-i-marshrutizacija-v-prilozhenii. Не могу понять:

у меня есть маршруты:

```
'/home'
'/home/nav_one'
'/home/nav_one/nav_two'
'/home/contacts'
'/home/contacts/description'
```

и были выполнены переходы:

```
'/home' -> '/home/nav_one' -> '/home/nav_one/nav_two' -> '/home/contacts/description'
```

Куда вернёт команда: Navigator.pop():
В `'/home/nav_one/nav_two'` или `'/home/contacts'` ?

Если в первый вариант, тогда зачем мы пишем эти самые маршруты, ради удобства чтения и понимания?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Как работает навигация в Flutter

Работает она по принципу стека (`stack`), он представляет из себя "стопку", где можно забрать тот предмет, который положил последним в "стопку". Для стека используются две основные операции - `push` и `pop`. `Push` - добавить элемент в стек, `pop` - удаляем элемент из стека.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Все остальные разновидности операций для работы с навигацией, являются модифицируемыми версиями `push` и `pop`.

### Для чего делать именованные маршруты? *И как они работают...*

В Flutter есть два вида создания нового маршрута.

По классам (декларация происходит в момент перехода):

```
Navigator.push(
  context,
  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomeScreen()),
);
```

И по имени:

```
Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/home_screen');
```

Но для работы по имени маршрута нам необходимо также задекларировать куда он будет вести:

```
{
  ...
  '/home_screen': (context) => HomeScreen(),
  ...
}
```

И передать это все в `routes` приложения (`MaterialApp`, `CupertinoApp` и т.д.).

*У обеих подходов есть свои плюсы и минусы во время работы. Но чем больше приложение (от 15 экранов), тем сложнее становиться использовать навигацию по классам...*

---

`Navigator.pop();` вернет `'/home/nav_one/nav_two'`

Comment: Я знаю как работает стек, но ответ очнь хороший и отвечает на мой вопрос. Спасибо!

Comment: Пожалуйста! Специально дал подробное объяснение для других людей, кто будет искать схожий вопрос.